# Use 'forceget' error when calling GET :urn/​metadata/​:guid/​properties

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I am trying to retrieve the properties using this method: GET :urn/​metadata/​:guid/​properties

This is something that we have running and works daily in our workflows, but I think this is an especailly large model.

For this particular model we are getting the following repsonse:

```
413 Request Entity Too Large
{Diagnostic": "Please use the 'forceget' parameter to force querying the data."}
```

Can anyone advise me as to how I do apply the forceget parameter to this call as I can't see any mention of it in the api docs.

Comment: This is a new feature that we're exposing, I'm checking that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **forceget** (string): To force get the large resource even if it exceeded the expected maximum length. Possible values: `true`, `false`. The implicit value is `false`.

Comment: Can this be added to the C# API on github? I have no way to add querystring parameters (such as objectid) to the API calls, which means I have to fall back on doing the web request by hand.

Comment: I'm planning to do include it along with a few minor changes, but may need a few more days.

Comment: Who do we need to speak to, to get it added to the Java API as well?

Comment: @Neil_M I’m coordinating with the Java SDK maintainers

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves There is still no forceGet option added to the Java API, do you have contact details for the SDK maintainers so we can chase this up further?

Answer (score 1):

The maximum data size 'without' forceget=true, is 2097152 bytes gzip compressed.

If you add 'forceget' then there is no size limit, however, if the generation of the gzip file takes longer than 2 hours, it will time out and try again later and eventually give up and report an error.

More details in this blog post: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/faster-get-hierarchy-api-and-how-solve-error-413
[image]

Answer (score 0):

@augusto-goncalves. Do you know what is the max number of parameters that are possible to get through a request with 'forceget' param?

Comment: With forceget enabled... There is not limit on the number of parameters.   However it is limited to 2hours of processing (opening svf and extracting into the JSON output).   So it will generate as many parameters as it can until the 2hr timeout occurs.   So the metric limit isn't based on parameter count, but CPU processing time.

Answer (score 0):

... and what is the maximum number of properties we might have in the model so that we can retrieve all properties from that endpoint WITHOUT using 'forceget' parameter?

Comment: see my answer above